# How to match cid string with python regex

Tags: python

I would like to find `9A5CA00DCF7842D99534F2F486FB7E5A` in

```
...tps://urlshortener.teams.microsoft.com/8D8660148021F90-7-10" style="text-decoration:none"><img height="16" width="14" style="vertical-align:middle; height:16px; width:14px" data-outlook-trace="F:1|T:1" src="cid:9A5CA00DCF7842D99534F2F486FB7E5A"></a></td>
```

So I need a regex that matches the string after cid: until (not including) the "

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import re

s = '...tps://urlshortener.teams.microsoft.com/8D8660148021F90-7-10" style="text-decoration:none"><img height="16" width="14" style="vertical-align:middle; height:16px; width:14px" data-outlook-trace="F:1|T:1" src="cid:9A5CA00DCF7842D99534F2F486FB7E5A"></a></td>'

print(re.search(r'cid:([0-9A-F]+)', s).group(1))
```

---

Or:

```
print(re.search(r'cid:([^"]+)', s).group(1))
```

Prints:

```
9A5CA00DCF7842D99534F2F486FB7E5A
```

---

Note: Is recommended to parse HTML with suitable library, for example `beautifulsoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')
print(soup.img['src'].split(':')[1])
```

Prints:

```
9A5CA00DCF7842D99534F2F486FB7E5A
```

Comment: Nice, is there a less strict way as to regarding the [0-9A-F], like 'everything until the first "'?

Comment: @Niels You can use `print(re.search(r'cid:([^"]+)', s).group(1))`

Comment: Does anyone maybe know a simple way of replacing all cid images src parts with their respective base64 encoded version... like replace the 1st one with image A and the 2nd one with image B

Comment: @Niels To not clutter the comment section, I recommend to open a new question here on StackOverflow (with sample input/desired output).

Comment: This only finds the first occurence, I would like to have an array with all occurences of the cid strings

Comment: @mplungjan First, check what interpreter are you running in Atom. Might be that you're using virtual environment in Atom and you've installed `bs4` in some other Python installation (`pip install bs4`). Check what libraries have you installed with `python -m pip freeze`

Comment: @mplungjan So you have `beautifulsoup` installed. When you run your script you're using python2.7 or python3? Python3 should work (with installed libraries).

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Atom runs 2.7 - I thought it was clever enough to pick up the latest version. I will delete my comments and re-visit how to run v3 in Atom. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```regex
(?:cid:)([^"]*)
```

Use match group 1 from resulting matching object.

[Explanation](https://regexr.com/5da20)

Include more preceding characters in non-capturing group `(?:<string>)` if you see wrong matching results.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(re.search(r'src="cid:(\w*\d*)"', text).group(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Without regex (assuming cid is of constant length, say 32 in you case)

```
print (s[s.find("cid:"):][4:36])
```